# Finding unique values with their occcrrences in XPath 2.0 or 3.0

Tags: xml, xpath

I have following XML

```
<Root>
    <Email>
        <Key> 1</Key>
    </Email>
    <Email>
        <Key> 1</Key>
    </Email>
    <Email>
        <Key> 2</Key>
    </Email>
    <Email>
        <Key> 2</Key>
    </Email>
    <Email>
        <Key> 3</Key>
    </Email>
</Root>
```

I am using XPATH 2.0 and can use XPATH 3.0 as well.
I need unqiue values for Key along with their occcurences. So I need following output.

1 (2 time), 2 (2 time),  3 (1 time)

I tried string-join(distinct-values(//Key) , ' ') function in XPATH 2.0 but I get only following from it

1 2 3

I am missing the occcurrences, tried using count function in string join but string join expects a separator as second input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPath has limitations. It cannot compose new constructs. For that you need to use XQuery.

Please try along the following.

**XPath 2.0**

```
for $x in distinct-values(/Root/Email/Key)
return concat($x, " - (", count(/Root/Email/Key[text()=$x]), " times)")
```

**Output**

```
1 - (2 times)
2 - (2 times)
3 - (1 times)
```

Comment: Thanks Yitzhak, I checked, and XQuery is supported in my system, so this solution works. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

In XPath 3.1 you could also create a map with `map:merge` and option `duplicates` as `combine` to then count the items in each map entry's value:

```
map:merge(/Root/Email/Key/map { normalize-space(): . }, map { 'duplicates' : 'combine' })
=> 
map:for-each(function($k, $v) { $k || ': ' || count($v) })
```